# Creating a tag using jQuery bootstrap-tagsinput without hitting the enter key

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events, onblur

I'm using `jquery bootstrap-tagsinput` and currently the only method for creating a tag is by hitting the enter key after typing it in. What I am looking for is a more easy user method of creating the tags. I was thinking that I could do an `onblur` somewhere in the `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` file.

Can someone assist?

[bootstrap tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Comment: [You mean this?](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) because it works onblur for me.

Comment: @JTG I apologize I did not know there were more plugins. I'm using the bootstrap plugin. I added the link to it. I might need to modify the vendor code.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the plugin itself (bootstratp-tagsinput.js) and add on blur event (I pretty much copied this one from on keydown event):

```
self.$container.on('blur', 'input', $.proxy(function(event) {
    var $input = $(event.target);

      if (self.options.freeInput) {
        self.add($input.val());
        $input.val('');
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      // Reset internal input's size
      $input.attr('size', Math.max(this.inputSize, $input.val().length));
    }, self));
```

Comment: It now has: addOnBlur: true.