# onBlur clear tt-input on bootstrap-tagsinput if not tagged

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, twitter-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

i m using jquery *bootstrap-tagsinput*, value should be select from suggestion list only, if not it will showing 'no record Found',

But actual problem is if value  not selected means onBlur i need to clear the [input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGFCq.jpg),So help me to recover this guys....

Comment: Can you copy your code there?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.bootstrap-tagsinput').data('tagsinput').$container
  .on('blur', 'input', function(event) {
     // Code here
});
```

Or see:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/25929132/7383715